# How to split AKS cluster subnet from pod subnet when using Azure CNI and a site-to-site VPN VNet

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

My goal is to run an AKS cluster which can be accessed by my on-premise network and of which the pods can access my on-premise network.

I have an on-premise network connected to Azure via a site-to-site VPN. The subnet of this site-to-site VPN is `10.10.6.0/24` in Azure to `10.9.6.0/24` on-premise. The DNS servers of this VNet are configured to my on-premise domain controllers.

I have set up an AKS cluster with this VNet, but to my surprise this means that every pod within this cluster gets an IP address of my VNet. According to the documentation this is intended behavior, but I didn't really expected this and it's not really what I wanted. A single site with two replica's and a cluster IP or internal load balancer eats away 3 of my precious IP addresses. I would like to have only the cluster IP get a subnet one.

I understand the reasons behind it, because obviously my pod's need to be able to access my on-premise network through the DNS configuration, but I was wondering if there's a way to split the cluster subnet and the pod subnet so that I don't exhaust the number of assignable IP addresses within my VNet? Just like it does when using kubenet instead of Azure CNI.

In theory I could extend my site-to-site VNet subnet to a /16 range, but I would prefer to look for an AKS solution first before changing my entire firewall configuration again.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only way around this is to use kubenet. as far as I know AKS Engine doesn't allow splitting pods and worker nodes ip addresses.

Comment: Is there a way to use kubenet and link the cluster to my on-premise vnet so that I can assign and consume internally defined fqdn's?

Comment: I'm not sure about the pods, but worker nodes would be able to use vpn, pods probably as well, but pods won't be reacheable unless you create routes over vpn (similar to how kubenet create user defined routes in Azure)

Comment: Do you have any links to tutorials or other material that might help me get on my way with this? I'm unsure how I can link an AKS VNet to my own VNet and have proper DNS working for my local, hybrid environment.

Comment: you'd need to use some sort of private dns, I'm guessing. it really depends on your setup

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old thread, but in case anyone still get here, Azure AKS now support node and pod in different subnet (same vnet) since around middle of 2022 (?), with something like below (azure portal won't work):

```
clusterName="myAKSCluster"
subscription="aaaaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaaa-aaaa"

az aks create -n $clusterName -g $resourceGroup -l $location \
  --max-pods 250 \
  --node-count 2 \
  --network-plugin azure \
  --vnet-subnet-id /subscriptions/$subscription/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$vnet/subnets/nodesubnet \
  --pod-subnet-id /subscriptions/$subscription/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$vnet/subnets/podsubnet
```

more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni#configure-networking---cli-with-dynamic-allocation-of-ips-and-enhanced-subnet-support